# Posteando una imagen aleatoria en Twitter con Python

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-api

estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto personal y mi duda es la siguiente:

Estoy tratando de que me seleccione una foto aleatoria de una carpeta y esa foto se postee en twitter, para ello he hecho dos documentos:
testing.py (que da un archivo de forma aleatoria):

```
import random, os
    path = r"/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/pics"
    random_filename = random.choice([
        x for x in os.listdir(path)
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
    ])
    print(random_filename)
```

y post.py que haría el proceso de twittear:

```
import tweepy
import testing
path = r"/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/pics/"
var = testing.result

def main():
    twitter_auth_keys = {
        "consumer_key": "BORRADA",
        "consumer_secret": "BORRADA",
        "access_token": "BORRADA",
        "access_token_secret": "BORRADA"
    }

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_key'],
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_secret']
    )
    auth.set_access_token(
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token'],
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token_secret']
    )
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
# Upload image
media = api.media_upload(./pics/var)
# Post tweet with image
tweet = 'Pic 4'
post_result = api.update_status(status=tweet, media_ids=[media.media_id])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
> > /home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/venv/bin/python /home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py
> 17.jpg <module 'testing' from '/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/testing.py'> Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py", line 32, in
> <module>
>     main()   File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/Post.py", line 25, in main
>     media = api.media_upload(pic)   File "/home/victor/PycharmProjects/PybotProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/api.py",
> line 223, in media_upload
>     file_type = imghdr.what(filename)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imghdr.py", line 19, in what
>     location = file.tell() AttributeError: module 'testing' has no attribute 'tell'
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: ¿Por qué está pasando un módulo (`testing`) a `media_upload()`?

Comment: Hola Hernan, estoy intentando que el resultado que me da en el primer archivo, me lo utilice para que sea el nombre del archivo de la publicación que se va a subir

Comment: Creo que tiene una confusión acerca de cómo funcionan los módulos. ¿Ha leído esto: https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/modules.html?

Comment: Se lo agradezco, lo he leido y he actualizado el codigo, igualmente no consigo el resultado porque no sé como hacer para que el resultado del primer modulo me lo ejecute en el `media_upload()` desde la ruta que lo tiene que hacer, que es ./pics/ que es donde tengo almacenadas las fotos, si están en la misma carpeta, sí me lo coge, sino no, porque no sé como meter la ruta

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente he conseguido arreglar el codigo, como no podía pasar un módulo por la variable `media_upload()`, he utilizado el módulo os para navegar hacia el directorio hijo ´pics´ y así poder seleccionar la foto, una vez hecho, volver al directorio padre con `os.chdir(back)`

el codigo resuelto del archivo Post.py quedaría por tanto de la siguiente manera:

```
import tweepy
import os
import testing

# Definimos una variable para que almacene el resultado del modulo que hemos creado anterior.
var = testing.result
# Damos las credenciales para el login en la API de Twitter
def main():
    twitter_auth_keys = {
        "consumer_key": "BORRADA",
        "consumer_secret": "BORRADA",
        "access_token": "BORRADA",
        "access_token_secret": "BORRADA"
    }
# Autentificamos y relizamos el proceso de log-in en Twitter
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_key'],
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_secret']
    )
    auth.set_access_token(
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token'],
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token_secret']
    )
    api = tweepy.API(auth)


    # Realizamos un proceso de cambio de directorio de trabajo
    back = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir("./pics/")

    # Definimos la variable de subida de la imagen que vamos a utilizar
    media = api.media_upload(var)

    # Definimos cual es el texto que va a utilzar el tweet como status
    tweet = var

    # Posteamos el tweet con la imagen
    post_result = api.update_status(status=tweet, media_ids=[media.media_id])

    # Vuelta al directorio padre
    os.chdir(back)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```